# Output dbt variable only if defined

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to output a dbt variable into a jinja template conditional on that variable being defined. Alas, my naive attempt does not seem to work:

```
{% if var('my_variable') is defined %}WHERE f.source_date < '{{ var('my_variable') }}'::DATE{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is `undefined`, try with `is not none`. So your code transforms into:

```
{% if var('my_variable') is not none %}WHERE f.source_date < '{{ var('my_variable') }}'::DATE{% endif %}
```

If this gives an error at compilation phase because the variable is not found in config ("Compilation Error in model ... Required var 'my_variable' not found in config: ..."), you can use `var('my_variable', 'default_value')`, replacing `default_value` by whatever you need.

In your case, you can write for example:

```
WHERE f.source_date < '{{ var('my_variable', '2999-12-31') }}'::DATE
```

to give it a default value that is always greater than all the dates you want to check with.

If, in the compiled code, you don't want to see the unnecessary WHERE clause, you can write:

```
{% if var('my_variable', none) is not none %}WHERE f.source_date < '{{ var('my_variable', none) }}'::DATE{% endif %}
```

Finally, to make it more visual, I would give a self-explanatory name to 'my_variable' and write:

```
{% set my_variable = var('my_variable', none) %}
{% if my_variable is not none %}WHERE f.source_date < '{{ my_variable }}'::DATE{% endif %}
```

If this variable is used in more than one model, think about defining the default value for this variable in dbt_project.yml, so that it will always be defined.

I think that this finally solves your problem. Good luck!

Comment: That doesn't work. If `my_variable` is not defined, `var()` errors.

Comment: Is there any value your variable cannot take? Like None or ''? We always give default values to variable. If not, dbt gives a compilation error. If your variable is not defined at compilation step only, you can embed the logic inside an 'if execute' block.

Comment: Hi @RoyalTS, I just improved my answer so that it works in case the var 'my_variable' is not found in the config. If it helps, feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: Hi @RoyalTS, I changed my first answer for it to be able to be applied to your use case. Could you finally solve the problem?